# What is the correct query to

Tags: mysql

I have a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT j_stats.j_id, js.title, j_stats.date_viewed, COUNT(j_stats.date_viewed) AS num 
FROM js 
INNER JOIN j_stats 
WHERE j_stats.j_id = 3 and js.j_id = 3;
```

It returns:

```
j_id | title   | date_viewed | num
  3  | <title> |  2015:11:24 |  18
```

However, I want to split the number of views into the number of views per date_viewed instead of the total number of views so that it looks like this:

```
j_id | title   | date_viewed | num
  3  | <title> |  2015:11:24 |  6
  3  | <title> |  2015:11:23 |  4
  3  | <title> |  2015:11:22 |  5
  3  | <title> |  2015:11:21 |  3
```

I have tried grouping by date_viewed but can't get the syntax right (I'm not sure this is the way forward for this query, either...) I'm a bit of a novice with MySQL and cannot get the format I need. How can I alter my query to achieve the results I need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `GROUP BY` at the end

```
GROUP BY j_stats.date_viewed
```

That will group the results of your `COUNT` based on each date. Rest is all fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get the desired result

`SELECT j_stats.j_id, js.title, j_stats.date_viewed, count(j_stats.date_viewed) AS num FROM js inner JOIN j_stats WHERE j_stats.j_id = 3 and js.j_id = 3 group by j_stats.date_viewed;`

Comment: Tried this, can't group by num.

Comment: SELECT j_stats.j_id, js.title, j_stats.date_viewed, count(j_stats.date_viewed) AS num FROM js inner JOIN j_stats WHERE j_stats.j_id = 3 and js.j_id = 3 group by j_stats.date_viewed;

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by like:

```
SELECT j_stats.j_id, js.title, j_stats.date_viewed, count(j_stats.date_viewed) AS num FROM js inner JOIN j_stats WHERE j_stats.j_id = 3 and js.j_id = 3 group by j_stats.date_viewed;
```